# Setting JAVA_HOME at Android SDK

Tags: android, windows, sdk, java

I have some conflicts with the `JAVA_HOME` configuration
When I using the following code -

```
System.out.println(System.getenv("JAVA_HOME"));
```

I get - `C:\jdk1.6.0_23` which is the correct place.
But, When I run Ant command on an Android build.xml, I got the following error message -

> C:\android-sdk-windows\tools\ant\main_rules.xml:361: Unable to find a javac compiler;
>   com.sun.tools.javac.Main is not on the
>   classpath. Perhaps JAVA_HOME does not
>   point to the JDK. It is currently set
>   to "C:\jdk1.6.0_23\jre"

How it can be resolved?

Thanks,

Eyal

Comment: try setting ur PATH to C:\jdk1.6.0_23\bin\ and check.

Comment: How did you set the classpath?  Did you try opening a new command prompt?

Comment: I meant to ask how you set `JAVA_HOME`.

Answer (score 19):

To permanently set your JAVA_HOME Environment Variable under Windows to the JDK directory you've mentioned do the following:

1. Click Start, right click on Computer and select properties (you can
   also hold down the windows key and press the pause/break key).
2. Click on Advanced system settings on the left.
3. Click the Environment Variables button on the bottom.
4. Click the New... button below the System variables window.
5. Enter the following:

   ```
       Variable name: JAVA_HOME
       Variable value: C:\jdk1.6.0_23\
   ```
6. Click Ok, Ok, Ok, and close the system control panel you opened in step 1
7. Close and re-open your command prompt.

If you are using Eclipse then skip the steps above and do the following:

1. Click on the Window menu and choose Preferences.
2. Expand the Ant entry on the left and click on Runtime
3. Click on Global Entries in the Classpath tab on the right.
4. Click Add External JARs...
5. Navigate to C:\jdk1.6.0_23\lib and select tools.jar then click open.
6. Hit ok to Close the preferences Window.

In your situation however your best bet would probably be to simply append C:\jdk1.6.0_23\bin to your PATH env var using my first set of instructions above as a rough guideline.

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy c:\windows\system32\java.exe to c:\windows\syswow64
2. Set JAVA_HOME to path, use `/` instead of `\`

Answer (score -2):

Update your Java to 8.XXX using:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html

Before installing, make sure to unistall old version 7.XX and then everything should work.