# Android SDK and Java

Tags: java, android

Android SDK Manager complains "WARNING: Java not found in your path".

Instead of using the information from Windows registry, the software tries to search Java in the default installation folders, and fails (I don't install software in program files because I don't like space characters in my paths).  Of course I know how to modify the %PATH% environment variable. The question is — which Java does it need?

After installing the latest JDK, I’ve got 4 distinct versions of java.exe file, in the following 4 folders: system32, jre6\bin, jdk1.6.0_26\bin, and jdk1.6.0_26\jre\bin. Size ranges from 145184 to 171808. All of them print version “1.6.0_26” when launched with the “-version” argument. The one in system32 has .exe version “6.0.250.6”, the rest of them is “6.0.260.3”. All 4 files are different (I’ve calculated the MD5 checksums).

Q1. Which folder should I add to %PATH% to make the Android SDK happy?

Q2. Why does Oracle build that many variants of java.exe of the same version for the same platform?

Thanks in advance!

P.S. I'm using Windows 7 SP1 x64 home premium, and downloaded the 64-bit version of JDK, jdk-6u26-windows-x64.exe.

Comment: Maybe this topic will help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4382178/android-sdk-installation-doesnt-find-jdk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I got stuck in this same problem, and although that the above answer should work properly... it didn't work for me.

The only solution that fixed this problem for me is copying the installed jdk folder to folder C:\Program Files\ ... and name that folder Java!

I know that this doesn't make any sense! but that what solved my problem after it make me go crazy.

I hope the normal solutions would help your problem, otherwise; you might think of my ugly solution and I hope your problem gets fixed soon.

Thanks,
Mohamed A.Karim.

Comment: I just reinstalled JDK in the default location.

Answer (score 1):

1. jre6\bin should work. That's what I put in %PATH%.
2. JRE is the Java Runtime Environmen and JDK is the Java Development Kit).

   - jre6\bin comes from JRE.
   - jdk1.6.0_26\bin has the development kit binary files
   - jdk1.6.0_26\jre\bin  has an implementation of the Java Runtime Environment for use by the JDK

Please see [Contents of the JDK for more info](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/readme-142177.html)

Answer (score 1):

Try setting JAVA_HOME pointing to the jdk1.6.0_26 directory. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613046/setting-java-home-at-android-sdk) post.

Answer (score 0):

What helped me was changing one of Enviroment Variables (right-click on "my computer" then "Advanced system settings" or similar) named PATH. Using function "edit" i added this:

> C:\Program Files\Java;C:\Program Files\Java\;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_29;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_29\;C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_29\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_29\bin\

(one of those is sufficient, but I don't know which).

I have Windows Vista 32bit.

Answer (score 0):

replace "`program files' with "progra~1`" in your path

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, maybe because I installed JDK on E: instead of C:
Solved by creating a run.bat file with these:

```
set JAVA_HOME="E:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26"
set PATH=%PATH%;"E:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_26\bin"
call "sdk manager.exe"
```

Works perfectly
Perhaps the path did what I needed