# How to set environment variable for JAVA_home and tomcat_home in windows XP?

Tags: tomcat, classpath, environment-variables

I was going through **head first JSP and servlet**. At one stage it says ,to set environmental variables! I am stuck.

**Qus:**What are Environmental Variables? Why do we need them?

**Qus:** What is class Path? Why do we set it?

Comment: This should help - says Android in the title, but still applies to pure Java http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613046/setting-java-home-at-android-sdk/4873271#4873271

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Qus:What are Environmental Variables? Why do we need them?**

What I say a word **TIGER**, do u know what I am talking about. Your Answer is **NO**, obviously. But before this, if I said to you that **TIGER** means **yellow/orange with four legs, etc**. Now you got that right. Same manner when Operating System (Windows,Linux,etc) encounters

> javac

or

> tomcat_home

it will direct you to that path which you have specified in **Environment Variables**. For eg. C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin.

> **Qus: What is class Path? Why do we set it?**

When programing in Java, you make other classes available to the class you are writing by putting something like this at the top of your source file:

import org.javaguy.coolframework.MyClass
or sometimes you 'bulk import' stuff by saying:

import org.javaguy.coolframework.*
so later in your program when you say:

mine = MyClass.new();
the java virtual machine can know to load your compiled class.

It would be impractical to have the VM look through every folder on your machine, so you have to provide the VM a list of places to look. This is done by putting folder and jar files on your classpath.

Before we talk about how the classpath is set, lets talk about .class files, packages, and .jar files.

First, let suppose that MyClass is something you built as part of your project, and it is in a directory in your project called 'output'. The .class file would be at 'output/org/javaguy/coolframework/MyClass.class' (along with every other file in that package). in order to get to that file, your path would simply need to contain the folder 'output'... not the whole package structure, since your import statement provides all that information to the VM.

Now lets suppose that you bundle CoolFramework up into a .jar file, and put that CoolFramework.jar into a lib directory in your project. you would now need to put 'lib/CoolFramework.jar' into your classpath... the VM will look inside th jar file for the 'org/javaguy/coolpackage' part, and find your class.

So, classpaths contain:

jar files, and
paths to the TOP of package hierarchies.
How do you set your classpath?

The first way everyone seems to learn is with environment variables. On a unix machine, you can say something like:

export CLASSPATH=/home/myaccount/myproject/lib/CoolFramework.jar:/home/myaccount/myproject/output/
on a windows machine you have to go to your environment settings and either add or modify the value that s already there.

The second way is to use the -cp parameter when starting Java, like this:

java -cp "/home/myaccount/myproject/lib/CoolFramework.jar:/home/myaccount/myproject/output/"  MyMainClass
A variant on this third way is often done with a .sh or .bat file that calculates the classpath and passes it to java via the -cp parameter.

So whats the best way to do it?

Setting stuff globally via environment variables is bad... generally for the same kinds of reasons that global variables are bad. You change the CLASSPATH environment variable so one program works, and you end up breaking another program.

The -cp is the way to go... I generally make sure my CLASSPATH environment variable is an empty string where I develop, whenever possible, so that I avoid global classpath issues (some tools aren't happy when the global classpath is empty though - I know of two common, mega-thousand dollar licensed J2EE and Java servers that have this kind of issue with their command-line tools).

Answer (score 1):

see this is the best article ...please take a look at this

For setting environment variable for JAVA in windows Xp

http://www.javux.com/Notes/JavaWeb/Lesson1/Lesson1B.html

For Installing Tomcat

https://wiki.jasig.org/display/UPM40/Installing+Tomcat