# Having trouble setting up for eclipse for android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

So I've downloaded a bundle from teamtreehouse and I've tried installing it, but I'm having some problems. When I execute initial_setup, this is what I see:

```
C:\android>REM Create a new AVD

C:\android>echo "Creating a new AVD..."
"Creating a new AVD..."

C:\android>echo no   | .\sdk\tools\android create avd -n Android44 -t 1 --force

'"\java.exe"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'xcopy' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
ERROR: SWT folder '' does not exist.
Please set ANDROID_SWT to point to the folder containing swt.jar for your platfo
rm.

C:\android>echo "AVD created."
"AVD created."

C:\android>pause
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I did some research and mostly what I saw is changing the path, I tried it but it still gives me the same results.

Comment: Any particular reason why you didn't use the install from the Eclipse site?

Comment: Do yourself a favor, install the Android Studio instead.

Answer (score 0):

> '"\java.exe"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

probaly you need to add the Java path to the Environment Variables.

This is very useful taken from: [Setting JAVA_HOME at Android SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613046/setting-java-home-at-android-sdk)

- Click Start, right click on Computer and select properties (you can also hold down the windows key and press the pause/break key).
- Click on Advanced system settings on the left.
- Click the Environment Variables button on the bottom.
- Click the New... button below the System variables window.
  Enter the following:

  Variable name: `JAVA_HOME`

  Variable value: `C:\jdk1.6.0_23\`  (*the path where java is located in your computer)
- Click Ok, and close the system control panel you opened in step 1