# JAVA_HOME Path works for Java but not for Android Studio

Tags: java, android, jvm

THIS QUESTION DOESNT HAVE AN ANSWER, THERE IS NO DAMN BACK BUTTON IN MY CASE!!!

Solution: ITS STILL NOT WORKING IN JDK8, you have to use ordinary Android SDK or Android Studio with JDK7! Thanks to Elliot Frisch's comment.

i hope thats the right metasite for that kind of stuff. i have properly installed java JRE and Java JDK. I can compila and execute java from commandline but if i try to install androi studio i get an error that JAVA_HOME doesnt point to a valid JVM installation.

are there additional things i have to install before using android studio or is the JAVA_HOME path different for android studio?

i put

```
C:/.../jre.x.x
C:/.../jre.x.x/bin
C:/.../jdk.x.x
C:/.../jdkx.x/bin
```

to my JAVA_HOME Path.

Comment: I recommend to see these pages

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4382178/android-sdk-installation-doesnt-find-jdk

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613046/setting-java-home-at-android-sdk

Comment: Sry of course i use Backticks on Windows8. For the other one see my answer on GreenDay's comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, set your `JAVA_HOME` to only one folder (and it's the parent of `bin`)

```
set "JAVA_HOME=C:/.../jdk.x.x"
```

Add it to your path like

```
set "PATH=%PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin"
```

Comment: I alredy added it to my JAVA_HOME Path. Again, java and javac works!

Comment: You gave four examples, only one is correct. Next, what version of the JDK are you using?

Comment: JDK 1.8.0.25 and also JRE 1.8.0.25. of course i tried all paths after another ;) why java works fine while Android Studio not? They dont have to use same Variables? i dont use android JDK, i use Android studio. is tere a difference?

Comment: I believe [Android Studio doesn't work with Java 8 yet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17869069/which-jdk-version-language-level-is-required-for-android-studio).

Comment: thanks, i heard about that issue because android studio is in something like a beta mode?!? so i thing thats the right answer, thank you but i cant give rep for your comment. android SDK works for sure on Win8 64Bit?

Comment: Works on Win 8, yes. Not JDK/JRE 8. You need Java JDK 7, which does work on Win 8.

Comment: sry for that stupid question but is it possible to run both? 7 + 8?

Comment: Yes, but you need to install 7 for Android Studio (you can also have 8 installed if you want, but you can't use Java 8 features, directly, yet for Android).

Comment: install JRE7 or JDK7?

Comment: Java Developer Kit 7, or JDK7 for short. Not the Java Runtime Environment.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to see these pages for more information, and always search before asking, I'm sure you can find the answer more quickly.

[Android SDK installation doesn't find JDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4382178/android-sdk-installation-doesnt-find-jdk)

[Setting JAVA_HOME at Android SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613046/setting-java-home-at-android-sdk)

in windows just setting 
JAVA_HOME environment variable to only "C:\Program Files\Java\jdkx.x.x_xx" is enough.

x x x -> relate to your JDK version.

C:\Program Files\Java\ -> depend to your java installation directory

Comment: To the first Link: In my case there is no back button.. http://picload.org/image/cccoroc/screenshot10.png And to the 2nd Link my Home_Path works for Java, why not for Android Studio? How should i place 2 Paths in 1 Variable? I have to include both, not?

Comment: please dont recommend irrelevant links.