# Android Studio JDK, JAVA_HOME does not effect the path

Tags: java, android-studio, jvm

No matter which path do i use for JAVA_HOME variable it does not effect android studio path for finding JDK, i tried restarting the computer after changing the path and it still doesnt work, Image Attached.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set java\_home on Windows 7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619584/how-to-set-java-home-on-windows-7)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting JAVA\_HOME at Android SDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4613046/setting-java-home-at-android-sdk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for replaying
i solved it by setting up the a new variable named PATH and set it to my JDK bin folder

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Use this format -

```
 variable name : JAVA_HOME
 variable value : C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_11\jre
```

[image]